# IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2 (List Scheduling )

Tags: python-2.7, indexoutofboundsexception, scheduling

I have a problem when trying to schedule the following. There appears to be an error in the for loop. In particulary in this part: `mM[iRow,j] = p[k]`.
But I don't understand what is wrong.

```
m=2  # machines
n= 4  # number of jobs
p= np.array([1,2,3,4])  # processing times
iTimemax = np.sum(p)

# Initialisation
iTime = 0
k= 0                    
iRow = 0  # the iRowth job of the machine
mM=np.zeros((n,m))

for i in range (iTimemax):
    for j in range (m):
        if np.sum(mM[:,j])  <= iTime:
            mM[iRow,j] = p[k]
            k = k + 1  # next job to be assigned
    iRow = iRow + 1
    iTime = iTime +1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of your p array is 4 and you are incrementing k every time it gets in the if condition. You need to either add a check in your if condition or reset k in the outer loop.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
m=2  # machines
n= 4  # number of jobs
p= np.array([1,2,3,4])  # processing times
iTimemax = np.sum(p)

# Initialisation
iTime = 0
k= 0
iRow = 0  # the iRowth job of the machine
mM=np.zeros((n,m))
for i in range (iTimemax):
    for j in range (m):
        if np.sum(mM[:,j])  <= iTime and k < len(p):
            mM[iRow,j] = p[k]
            k = k + 1  # next job to be assigned
    iRow = iRow + 1
    iTime = iTime +1
```